# How do i get column values of my sql table dynamically using stored procedures?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am learning stored procedures. Coming to the problem I have a table where columns are named as Q1,Q2,Q3...,Q10 . I want to retrieve these values dynamically using while loop (or for loop). I tried something but that didn't give me actual output. Please give me some suggestions.

**My code is as follows :**

```
 delimiter //
    drop procedure if exists exam//
    create procedure exam ()
    begin
    declare a int default 1;
    while a <= 9 do 
    select  concat(Q,a) from feed1 where col = 'XYZ';
    set a= a + 1;
    end while;
    end ;
    //
    delimiter ;
    call exam;
```

When i run this i am getting an error **" Unknown column Q in field list "**

Comment: 1. See normalization - or forget about using an RDBMS

Comment: So, can't i do  like this ?? @strawberry..

Comment: The point is, why would you? You're not utilizing any of the advantages of relational data, so you may as well just keep everything in a flat file. A database is NOT a spreadsheet.